# Merging Pandas dataframes on same column identifier with improper output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** I have a code that reads a set of excel files from a directory and gathers the contents of each to a dataframe in a list then concatenates it. The code also reads another file where it gets the data for some identifiers into another dataframe.

**Example of data in the concatenated dataframe from the list:**

```
Iteration        Run        Value
 9154aa           3          100
 9154aa           7          112
 9154aa           1          120
 3148nf           77         58
 3148nf           7          86
 9421jh           23         27
 9421jh           42         736
 9421jh           4          44
 9421jh           9          82
```

**Example of the other dataframe:**

```
Iteration      Date
 9154aa      01012011
 1582he      01052013
 3148nf      01092011
 9421jh      01012010
```

The first DF has information for multiple iterations concatenated, while the additional DF has a piece of information for all iterations.

**Objective:** My objective is to put the date related to a iteration into the first dataframe (in every row that corresponds to that iterations).

**Output Example:**

```
Iteration        Run        Value       Date
 9154aa           3          100      01012011
 9154aa           7          112      01012011
 9154aa           1          120      01012011
 3148nf           77         58       01092011
 3148nf           7          86       01092011
 9421jh           23         27       01012010
 9421jh           42         736      01012010
 9421jh           4          44       01012010
 9421jh           9          82       01012010
```

**Issue:** Although the script runs with no crashes, for some reason my output is duplicating one (or more) of my iteration entries.

**Example of flawed output:**

```
Iteration        Run        Value       Date
 9154aa           3          100      01012011
 9154aa           7          112      01012011
 9154aa           1          120      01012011
 3148nf           77         58       01092011
 3148nf           77         58       01092011
 3148nf           7          86       01092011
 3148nf           7          86       01092011
 9421jh           23         27       01012010
 9421jh           42         736      01012010
 9421jh           4          44       01012010
 9421jh           9          82       01012010
```

I have no idea of the reason for this behavior.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
sourcefolder = "\\Network\DGMS\2018"
outputfolder = "\\Network\DGMS\2018"
adjustmentinputs = "//Network/DGMS/Uploader_v1.xlsm"
selectmonth = input("Please enter month ('January', 'February'...):")

# Get Adjustments
ApplyOnDates = pd.read_excel(open(adjustmentinputs, 'rb'), sheet_name='Calendar')

# Get content
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(sourcefolder, "*.xls*"))
contentdataframes = []
contentdataframes2 = []

for f in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    df['Iteration'] = os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0].split('_')[0]
    mask = df.columns.str.contains('Base|Last|Fix')
    c2 = df.columns[~mask].tolist()
    df = df[c2]
    contentdataframes.append(df)
    print (f)

concatenatedfinal = pd.concat(contentdataframes)

# Date Adjustment 
ApplyOnDates = ApplyOnDates[["IT", selectmonth]]
ApplyOnDates = ApplyOnDates.rename(index=str, columns={"IT": "Iteration", selectmonth: "Date"})

Datawithfixeddates = pd.DataFrame.merge(concatenatedfinal, ApplyOnDates, left_on='Iteration', right_on='Iteration', indicator=False)
```

**OBS:** In the example I used only a small amount of data, while normally it would do it for dozens of iterations.

Comment: change your merge and add the parameter how='left'

Comment: @Yuca Already tried that, also does not work.

Comment: since I don't have your data, there's nothing more I can do to help. 'left' should fix it if the data is actually clean

Comment: @Yuca I found the error, my code was duplicating some of the entries of the second DF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a left join here. As per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), left join preserves all of the values in the first DataFrame, subbing in values from the second dependent on the structure of the first.

Set the parameter  `pd.DataFrame.merge(how='left')`

For your data as below:

```
In[13]: print(df1)
Out[13]: 
Iteration  Run  Value
0    9154aa    3    100
1    9154aa    7    112
2    9154aa    1    120
3    3148nf   77     58
4    3148nf    7     86
5    9421jh   23     27
6    9421jh   42    736
7    9421jh    4     44
8    9421jh    9     82
```

and

```
In[15]: print(df2)
Out[15]: 
Iteration      Date
0    9154aa  01012011
1    1582he  01052013
2    3148nf  01092011
3    9421jh  01012010
```

The following is true

```
In[16]: print(df1.merge(df2,left_on='Iteration',right_on='Iteration',how='left'))
Out[16]: 
Iteration  Run  Value      Date
0    9154aa    3    100  01012011
1    9154aa    7    112  01012011
2    9154aa    1    120  01012011
3    3148nf   77     58  01092011
4    3148nf    7     86  01092011
5    9421jh   23     27  01012010
6    9421jh   42    736  01012010
7    9421jh    4     44  01012010
8    9421jh    9     82  01012010
```

Comment: Found the error, my code was duplicating some of the entries of the second DF